# Unable to get Customer Details in block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

**My code is**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace My\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Abc extends Template
{

    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }

    public function getCustomerDetail(){
            if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
                echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
                echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
                echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();  
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below model factory code.

```
protected $_sessionFactory;

/**
 * @param Template\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory  
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_sessionFactory = $sessionFactory;

}

public function getCustomerDetail(){
        $customerSession  = $this->_sessionFactory->create();
        if($customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()) {
        echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
        echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
      }
    }
```

}

Comment: @thank you so much, there was typo error I have edited.